# Creating incremental statistic bars on Android

Tags: android

I'm a bit new to Android. I'm trying to show multiple vertical bars that each increments by one upon frequent data receipt, something similar to the following figure:

[image]

You can think about each of these bars as different entities (e.g. users) with different IDs. So there is assumed to be a method `update (ID)`, that upon receipt of an ID, it increments the corresponding color bar by one and updates the UI. It is assumed that lots of IDs are given to this method per each time units.

Wondering if someone has experience of this application and could help with efficient APIs to code this.

Comment: It's called `BarChart`. I think that [aChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html) can do for you. Or [GraphView](http://android-graphview.org/)

Comment: @DerGolem Do you know of any sample code? I could not find any.

Comment: aChartEngine provides a very rich demo. I thinkk GraphView also does. However, on the download page there's some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's libraries to create charts of all kinds (bar chart in your case), namely [GraphView](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView) and 
[AChartEngine](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/). You can also do this by yourself by programmatically creating `Views` and giving them their heights and background colors. 
I've done this and it was a pain in the rear, so I'd definitely check one of the aforementioned libraries.

Comment: I wish you were using it, so you could post a sample code. I'm having problem finding a good documentation for that.